# Generating single-frequency sound with Python, but no sound is produced

Tags: python, audio

I just got a new Raspberry Pi 4 and am trying to write a Python program that generates a sound that's just one frequency. However, I am having a problem that I cannot hear any sound coming out of the program at all. Here is the code I am using.

```
import pyaudio
import numpy as np

p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
print(p.get_default_output_device_info())
volume = 1     # range [0.0, 1.0]
fs = 48000       # sampling rate, Hz, must be integer
duration = 100   # in seconds, may be float
f = 440.0        # sine frequency, Hz, may be float

# generate samples, note conversion to float32 array
samples = (np.sin(2*np.pi*np.arange(fs*duration)*f/fs)).astype(np.float32)

# for paFloat32 sample values must be in range [-1.0, 1.0]
stream = p.open(format=pyaudio.paFloat32,
                channels=2,
                rate=fs,
                output=True)
# play. May repeat with different volume values (if done interactively) 
stream.write(volume*samples)

stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()

p.terminate()
```

I took this code from another question on this site regarding generating the sound I mentioned. The only changes I made were to observe my device's info and to change the sampling rate to my device's default. If I did not change my sampling rate, the program would produce an error. As it is, the program simply runs indefinitely, all the while producing no sound. If I stop the program, a pop can be heard from the speakers.

Now, the Pi itself produces audio output just fine. I have tested both playing audio to HDMI and Analog, with YouTube from the browser, and playing a wav file in Python using the `playsound` library.

So, I am quite confused as to why the program above produces no sound. Any insight would be appreciated. Thank you very much in advance.

EDIT: I have also noticed that the program runs indefinitely, even when I set the duration to 1 second.

Comment: might be playing on the wrong audio output.  are you listening on hdmi or audio jack?

Answer (score 0):

The pop means you've got some control over the speakers. Good. Maybe, your program is telling the speakers to work too quietly. Look for things that would cause that: Have you tried volume=1.0 or maybe volume=0.99? Maybe Python isn't coercing the integer 1 into the float 1.0. Double check that your samples array is populated with values of the expected range.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the answer. I've tried changing the volume like you suggested, but still nothing. Also, the samples array is populated with oscillating values between [-1,1] as expected. I have also noticed that the program runs indefinitely, even when I set the duration to 1 second. Would you happen to have any other suggestions?

Comment: Did you change all the numeric constants that should be float to use a decimal point? Fortran and C are famously bad at converting nothing from int to float (or vice versa), and TypeScript is very forgiving at inferring what types you want from how they're used. Python I don't know well enough to say without coding up a small experiment.

Comment: Yes, I have done so as you suggested in your first answer. Unfortunately, there is still nothing.